# How can I fix this [could not find method layout()]

Tags: android, gradle, artifactory

I installed `com.jfrog.artifactory` plugin correctly using Gradle 7.+.

Now, I read the documentaion to complete my installation [Gradle Artifactory Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) , but as the following image shown I got that error ! `Could not find method layout()`

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the layout pattern to be optional, a definition like below for the artifact resolution [Ivy] should help. Please check.

```
  ivy {
    ivyLayout = '[organization]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml'
    artifactLayout = '[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]'
    mavenCompatible = true //Convert any dots in an [organization] layout value to path separators, similar to Maven's groupId-to-path conversion. True if not specified
  }
```

Comment: I make it `true` already. its different issue dude.  @Yuvarajan

Comment: That's a typo caused by copy/paste from the note. Please check whether the above-edited one helps.